# California water district boundaries

Tags: data-request, data.gov, geospatial

I'm looking for **California water district boundaries**, both private and public in any geographic format.

This data appears to be available on Data.gov **[HERE](http://catalog.data.gov/dataset/private-water-districts)** and **[HERE](http://catalog.data.gov/dataset/state-water-districts)**, but the links are dead.  I've contacted all the email addresses linked to from the metadata, and some other folks I found by both email and through Twitter.

The contact email is listed as metadata@gis.resources.ca.gov but delivery to that email address fails permanently.
Also, don't bother contacting Lorri Peltz-Lewis who is mentioned somewhere in the metadata.  She is helpful, but no longer works at the U.S. Bureau of Reclamation.
I've emailed the U.S. Bureau of Reclamation with no response so far.

If anyone has this data, or is willing to help me out **I would greatly appreciate it!**  I was about to give up, but have some very cool map visualizations in mind.

**EDIT:**  If anyone else is looking for this data, it's now converted to GeoJSON and **[available here](https://gist.github.com/pdbartsch/07277a0645fb2df9f729)**.  Make sure to read the README.md file.

Comment: I thought I had an answer, but the portal that it links to has broken links as well: http://atlas.ca.gov/geoportal/data/usbr/StateWaterDistricts/2003-03-25/usbr_wat_dist_state_2003_03_25.zip

Comment: Yep, I ended up there too.  Thanks for trying  @AndyEschbacher

Comment: Archive.org's wayback machine seem to have them (I haven't validated the content other than unzipping it and visually inspecting) : https://web.archive.org/web/%2a/http://projects.atlas.ca.gov/frs/download.php/245/usbr_wat_dist_state_2003_03_25.zip ; https://web.archive.org/web/%2a/http://projects.atlas.ca.gov/frs/download.php/26/usbr_wat_dist_priv.zip .

Comment: @Joe - you should post that as an answer

Comment: @Joe - that's a great idea.  I knew about the wayback machine but never thought of using it for something like this.  Thanks!

Comment: If anyone else needs this, here is the data in GeoJSON format as a GIST:  https://gist.github.com/pdbartsch/07277a0645fb2df9f729

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update:
this data is now available on open data se's datahub.io account, here:
http://datahub.io/dataset/california-water-district-boundaries

For those times when data *was* posted, but has since disappeared, you can try [The Internet Archive](https://archive.org/)'s [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/).  It does have some limitations, as it won't violate a robots.txt file and it may not archive large files, but in your particular case, it seems to have copies of the two files from 2009-2010:

- https://web.archive.org/web/%2a/http://projects.atlas.ca.gov/frs/download.php/245/usbr_wat_dist_state_2003_03_25.zip
- https://web.archive.org/web/%2a/http://projects.atlas.ca.gov/frs/download.php/26/usbr_wat_dist_priv.zip

I've verified that the most recent copies both unzip without errors, but I haven't done any other testing to determine if they're intact / complete.

Comment: Would you be interested to make a copy of this dataset at [the opendata.SX org on datahub.io](http://datahub.io/organization/opendata-stackexchange)?